# How do I enable the Bixby Studio for development on the TV, Watch and Appliances (Refrigerator)

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I would like to get a head start on developing for the watch, tv and refrigerator for Bixby. How do I enable these in the Bixby Developer Studio?

Answer (score 2):

You can start developing right now for these new devices. Marketplaces will roll out in 2020. To enable your capsule for additional devices, you need to modify the `targets` key in `capsule.bxb`- by default right now it looks like this:

```
  targets {
    target (bixby-mobile-en-US)
  }
```

To add the three additional devices:

```
  targets {
    target (bixby-mobile-en-US)
    target (bixby-tv-en-US)
    target (bixby-fridge-en-US)
    target (bixby-watch-en-US)
  }
```

the above would enable your capsule for all 3 new devices in the US English (en_US locale). For more information and options - see the docs at: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/capsule.targets.target

After this is done, when you select a capsule to run in the simulator, you can also make a selection for the target - See screenshot below. The simulator will then switch to the desired device

[image]